# How android:alpha can be more than 1.0?

Tags: android

I dragged an apk file to Android Studio to discover it, and found the below code as part of an xml file in the color resource directory.

Since `android:alpha` should be a value between 0.0 to 1.0, what does it mean?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="@attr/0x7f040192"
        android:alpha="1052938048.000000" />
</selector>
```

Comment: the `android:alpha` for color/drawable is between 0.0 to 255.0, if the value is larger or smaller you may get an **unexpected color**, you can see https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Color.java;drc=956a76ae36cfe0b5808abab81e3ccbc5c1fe3656;l=467 how argb is converted.